# Search for data in array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I have a search bar on top of my tableview, and it is searching using my data array "title"
I want to add also Id beside title, so the user can search using the title or post id
I tried this but it searches only using the id

```
  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    print("text did change")
    if searchText.count != 0 {
        self.isSearch = true // item["title"].string
        self.searchedData = self.data.filter { ($0["title"].string?.contains(searchText))! }
        self.searchedData = self.data.filter { ($0["id"].string?.contains(searchText))! }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        self.isSearch = false
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

}

is it possible to search also for title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue there is that you are assign the result of your second filter and discarding the result of the previous filter.

You shouldn't force unwrap the result of your expression. Just check if it is true. Note that you can avoid iterating your data twice `{ $0["id"].string?.contains(searchText) == true || $0["title"].string?.contains(searchText) == true }`